# How do I remove the white space between these two blocks?

Tags: html, css, email, newsletter, hubspot

I have no idea how to code....so can someone help me in removing the white space between these two blocks? I am writing a newsletter. Also, is it possible to move the image to the left side and the text to the right side for the second section? Thanks!!

```
<!-- SECTION - POST 1 CUP --> <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:450px;margin:0 auto;padding:30px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:42px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %} {% widget_attribute "html" %} <h4 style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:{{widget_data.color_2.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:23px;font-weight:700;line-height:28px;margin:20px 0 20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:0;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">Meet Our Team.</h4> <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:0px;padding:0;text-align:left">Text placeholder.</p> {% end_widget_attribute %} {% end_widget_block %} </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:-0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:20px 20px 20px;"> <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/685080/HubSpot_Template_Marketplace/Turbo_Vanadyl/images/mailings/post-before-footer.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:360px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin:0 auto;"> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <!-- SECTION - POST 2 CUP --> <table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:20px;margin:0 auto;padding:0px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:42px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %} {% widget_attribute "html" %} <p style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0;margin-bottom:0px;padding:0;text-align:left">Text placeholder</p> {% end_widget_attribute %} {% end_widget_block %} </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:30px 20px 20px;"> <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/685080/HubSpot_Template_Marketplace/Turbo_Vanadyl/images/mailings/post-before-footer.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:360px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;"> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`
```

Comment: I looked at your code and first off, it's minified, which makes it painful to troubleshoot. Second, I can't tell what white space you want to removed. Third, this is the sales number for Hubspot: (855) 405 8006. You're already  paying $800 a month for hosting and tech support. Take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

change the first image height to 100%

```
<img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/685080/HubSpot_Template_Marketplace/Turbo_Vanadyl/images/mailings/post-before-footer.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:100%;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin:0 auto;">
```

this takes care of the spaces between the boxes

Answer (score 0):

to switch the picture to the left on the second section do the following

`<table align="center" width="800" class="container footer float-center not-outlook" style="margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;height:20px;margin:0 auto;padding:0px 0 0!important;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;" align="center" class="container post-before-footer float-center">
       <tbody>
       <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> 
       <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;margin:0 0 0 0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> 
       <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th class="mobile-blog-posts blog-posts small-12 large-6 columns first" style="margin:0 auto;background:#fff;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;max-width:440px;padding:0!important;text-align:left;width:384px"> 
       <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> 
       <tbody> 
       <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="margin:0 0 0 0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0;text-align:left"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;margin:0 0 0 0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0;padding-left:55px;padding-top:42px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
       <img src="{% image_src 'section_before_src' label='Section before footer - Image (345px/340px)', src='https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/685080/HubSpot_Template_Marketplace/Turbo_Vanadyl/images/mailings/post-before-footer.png', no_wrapper=True %}" alt="Image for own posts" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;height:360px;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto;margin: 0 auto;"> 
        </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> <th class="image-before-footer small-12 large-6 columns last" style="margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:384px;background:#fff;"> <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <th style="margin:0 0 0 0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0;text-align:left"> 
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> 
        <td class="mobile-blog-posts" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;margin:0 0 0 0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0;padding-right:55px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;padding:30px 20px 20px;"> 
         {% widget_block rich_text "section_before_footer" overrideable=True, label='Section before footer - Text' %} 
        {% widget_attribute "html" %} 
        <p style="margin:0 0 0 0;margin-bottom:0px;color:{{widget_data.color_3.color}};font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Geneva, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;margin:0 0 0 0;margin-bottom:0px;padding:0;text-align:left">
        Text placeholder</p> {% end_widget_attribute %} {% end_widget_block %}

        </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </th> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`

Comment: Awesome - the alignment worked way better! I used the code you pasted and the white space is removed.

Comment: @Trish glad I can help could you mark my answer as the correct answer. 